# next and previous buttons running two swipe js carousels

Tags: javascript, carousel, swipe

I have two separate swipe carousels on one page but having trouble with the next and previous buttons working incorrectly.

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eybJZ/)

**HTML**

```
    Slider 1
<div id='slider1' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>
        <div>
            <div>0</div>
            <div>1</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>10</div>
            <div>11</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>12</div>
            <div>13</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button class='prev' onclick='slider1.prev()'>prev</button>
    <button class='next' onclick='slider1.next()'>next</button>
</div>Slider 2
<div id='slider2' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>
        <div>0</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>10</div>
        <div>11</div>
        <div>12</div>
        <div>13</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <button class='prev' onclick='mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button>
    <button class='next' onclick='mySwipe.next()'>next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that your assigning both Swipe instances to the same variable. Therefor the second instance overrides the first one. I've made an update to your fiddle solving this: http://jsfiddle.net/eybJZ/2/

Comment: Thanks @xat :) worked perfectly